# How to refresh a section or block of page by php with out reloding?

Tags: php, html

I write a timer in a table with tr and td tag by php, the below code show it

```
$time_now=time();
$time_check=$fetch_time ['time_vam_give']+($durday1*24*60*60);
$remaining=$time_check-$time_now;
$time_remain_day=floor(($remaining)/(24*60*60));
$hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
$minute_remainig=floor((($remaining % 86400) % 3600)/60);
$second_reminig=((($remaining % 86400) % 3600)%60);
Echo “<table><tr class='tr1' style='background-color: #CC8A10' >
<td class='td1' style='background-color: #CC8A10'>Day</td>
<td class='td1' style='background-color: #CC8A10'>Hour</td>
<td class='td1' style='background-color: #CC8A10'>Minute</td>
<td class='td1' style='background-color: #CC8A10'>Second</td></tr>
 <tr class='tr1'><td class='td1' style='background-color: #FC1359'>$time_remain_day</td>
<td class='td1' style='background-color: #FC1359'>$hours_remaining</td>
<td class='td1' style='background-color: #FC1359'>$minute_remainig</td>
<td class='td1' style='background-color: #FC1359'>$second_reminig</td></tr>”;
```

And for refresh I have one that refresh all of page be this code

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "5";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
```

But the refresh code, refresh all of page and all of object should be refreshed, I want only the code in table that contain Time’s variable, How can I do it? 
Additionally I use Iframe but using this tag such as  screen shot of page and it is not suitable and beauty.

```
echo " <iframe id='dynamic-content' src='../function/Func1.php' ></iframe>";
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to refresh without reloading you should use ajax

you can use something like this

make 2 php files the first **index.php**

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">

</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval(ajaxcall, 1000);
 });
 function ajaxcall(){
     $.ajax({
         url: 'gettime.php',
         success: function(data) {
             data = data.split(':');
             $('#days').html(data[0]);
             $('#hours').html(data[1]);
             $('#minutes').html(data[2]);
             $('#seconds').html(data[3]);
         }
     });
 }
</script>

<table>
    <tr class='tr1' style='background-color: #CC8A10'>
        <td class='td1' style='background-color: #CC8A10'>Day</td>
        <td class='td1' style='background-color: #CC8A10'>Hour</td>
        <td class='td1' style='background-color: #CC8A10'>Minute</td>
        <td class='td1' style='background-color: #CC8A10'>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='tr1'>
        <td class='td1' style='background-color: #FC1359'><span id="days">0</span></td>
        <td class='td1' style='background-color: #FC1359'><span id="hours">0</span></td>
        <td class='td1' style='background-color: #FC1359'><span id="minutes">0</span></td>
        <td class='td1' style='background-color: #FC1359'><span id="seconds">0</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and **gettime.php**

```html
<?php    
$time_now=time();
$time_check=$fetch_time ['time_vam_give']+($durday1*24*60*60);
$remaining=$time_check-$time_now;

$time_remain_day=floor(($remaining)/(24*60*60));
$hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
$minute_remainig=floor((($remaining % 86400) % 3600)/60);
$second_reminig=((($remaining % 86400) % 3600)%60);

echo $time_remain_day . ':' . $hours_remaining . ':' . $minute_remainig . ':' . $second_reminig; 
?>
```

I hope that helped you

Comment: Thanks so much, that's useful for me and work correctly, but this code work on internet correctly. my web site located on private network in my country and  inaccessible from out side due it doesn't act . the first two row's code cause problem,  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" this how can i solve this problem?

Comment: this is because in the first 2 line I used the Jquery library witch is necessary for ajax from external link
so the solution is to download jquery from this link 
https://jquery.com/download/
and modify this line 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
replace the url with the location of the file in your project

Comment: if you will put the js in the same folder with the 2 php files it should be something like that 
<script src="../yourProjectFolder/jquery-2.2.0.min.js">

Comment: Dear Karmen, As previously mentioned, it work correctly but i test in some browser such as IE and Chrome it doesn't work and have some mistake, in IE it stopped and doesn't exist any communication between php file and Ajax, and in Chrome for each send-recive between Ajax and php file the page reload it cause a bad interface. can you help me.?

Comment: can you give me some screenshot of the problem ? and you didn't add something to the code ? because I remember it works well on chrome